# Django: Displaying a form from one model with content from a second model on one page view

Tags: django-forms

I have an irksome little problem with a forum that I am building.
I need to generate a page that contains a form to populate one
model but that page should also display an entry from another related model.
I want the form to populate a new response in the model Responses (see code below).
That model has the model StartMsg as a foreign key.  I want the page view (response_form) to display StartMsg.msg that the user is responding to.  The problem is that I am using django's built in forms to generate the form and render_to_response to call the page.  The render_to_response statement (marked (A)) sends a dictionary containing the form components from the Responses model to the html template.

How do I include info about the model StartMsg into the render_to_response statement (marked
with (A), below)?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I am after?

---

Here are the models:

```
class StartMsg (models.Model):
    msg_title = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    msg = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.msg

class Responses (models.Model):
    startmsg = models.ForeignKey(StartMsg) #one startmsg can have many responses
    response = models.TextField()
    responder = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.response
```

---

Below is the form processing function followed by the form model.

```
def response_form (request, msg_id):
    msg = get_object_or_404(StartMsg, pk=msg_id)
    form = MsgRespForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_rspns = form.save(commit =False)
        #retrieve StartMsg entry to assign to the response entry foreign key
        message = StartMsg.objects.get(pk=msg_id)
        new_rspns.startmsg = message
        response = form.cleaned_data['response']
        new_rspns.response = response
        new_rspns.responder= request.user.username()
        new_rspns.pub_date = datetime.now()
        new_rspns.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('forum.views.forum', )) #if form is processed, view goes here

    return render_to_response( #if form not processed, view goes here
        'forumresponseform.html',
        {'form': form},  (A)
        context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    )

class MsgRespForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Add Labels to form fields:
    response = forms.CharField(label='Your Response',
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 60, 'rows': 10}))
    class Meta: #Define what fields in the form
        model = Responses
        fields = ('response',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work.
You can make a function that builds a dictionary out of a variable number of model queries then pass that dictionary to the form template on line (A).

```
def build_dict(request, ** kwargs):
    d = dict(user=request.user, ** kwargs)
    return d

msg = get_object_or_404(StartMsg, pk=msg_id)
form = MsgRespForm(request.POST or None)
dict = build_dict(request, msg=msg, form=form)

return render_to_response( #if form not processed, view goes here
    'forumresponseform.html',
    {'form': dict},  (A)
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
)
```